# dynamic variables attached to specific divs

Tags: jquery

I have several divs with one class on a page.

`<div class="main"/>
    <div class="main"/>
    <div class="main"/>
    ...`

I need to attach a variable to each div with a boolean true or false, depending on the click on this div. All these variables should have a default false value, and if I click on a certain div the value of a variable attached to this div should become true. I don't know how much divs there will be as they appear dynamically on a page, so the variables should be attached according to the number of these divs on a page, and they must have a global scope so I could modify them in future. Appreciate all your ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method for that purpose:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").data("yourKey", false).click(function() {
        $(this).data("yourKey", true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is very interesting. Is there a way to check the data value? if($('div', this).data('yourKey') == true) {do some stuff}

Comment: @tylik, yes, you can use the one-argument form of `data()` to do that, like in your example: `if ($(selector).data("yourKey")) { doSomething(); }`

Comment: Thanks Frédéric,  I think this will do the case.

Answer (score 1):

***Solution:***

```
   $("div.main").click(function(){
    if($(this).html()=='false')
    {
    $("this").html('true');
    }
    else
   {
   $("this").html('false');
   }

    });
```

Comment: this will set to true the current div and reset to false all other divs and I need to remember each divs  state

Comment: See my edited code. If a div with false is clicked it return true. if again clicked on same div changes to false.

Comment: This should work but is still wonder why would $(this).html()=='false' . I mean that .html() =='false' should be a string, or probablyl I don't understand something. It should look something like this <div class="main">false</div> in order for it to work

Comment: I thought u are mentioning string 'true' or 'false'. Sorry @tylik. its possible to give boolean value to div. i think its not possible

Comment: It's o.k. Probably I didn't explain it right :) Fortunately Frédéric Hamidi pointed the right answer to me.